# HTML5 video .ended event called in Chrome, but not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a bit of jquery acting on an html5/video.js video tag:

```
$("#video").one("ended", function() {
    various animations on page;
}
```

The animations run in Chrome, but not FF. Other javascript works, and .bind/.on do the same thing. The video plays fine. Firebug doesn't notice any errors. It should be noted that Firefox can't play the mov/mp4 files, so it falls back to the ogg I specified. No looping, autoplay is on.

Anyone? Thank you bunch's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When video.js fell back to ogg video for Firefox, it wrapped the video in a different div (but not in chrome). Just selected it and it worked.